# How to use PushSharp with simple project

Tags: c#, pushsharp

I get the feeling that this question is either too basic or too complex to be covered by any documentation on [pushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp).  But how exactly do I incorporate it into my project. I am used to `Java`/`php`, etc and have never really looked at C# before. I have been reading whatever I can find but am not really sure what I should be looking at.

I have an `ashx` file that is handling my ajax calls and is currently using the example code from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/434338/Android-GCM-Push-Notification to send push notifications. I would really like to incorporate `pushSharp` so that I can do this for `ios` and windows as well but am feeling a bit lost as to how to do this.

With Java I would compile the library as a jar and include that in a project.  Would I do the same here by compiling the whole `pushsharp` project as a `dll` or each folder (android/ios etc) or have I got this completely wrong?  Any suggestions, or pointing me to the relevant tutorials/documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your qestion should be "how to use a c# library where only sourcecode but no dll is available". your problem has nothig to do with pushsharp

Comment: Thanks, I knew (was fairly sure) this wasn't specific to pushSharp but wasn't sure as their folder structure seemed unusual to my inexperienced eye.  Eventually grabbed it with nuget and all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @k3b did some research on this without considering pushsharp as being any different and got it resolved.  thanks.